# ros2 domain bridge: how to write yaml config file in python script?

Tags: ros2, python, yaml

I'm trying to write the yaml config file for the ROS2 [domain bridge](https://github.com/ros2/domain_bridge) from a python script. At the end it should like this:

```
name: ol_bridge
topics:
  simulation/odometry:
    type: nav_msgs/msg/Odometry
    from_domain: 88
    to_domain: 40
    remap: simulation/odom_88

  simulation/odometry:
    type: nav_msgs/msg/Odometry
    from_domain: 89
    to_domain: 40
    remap: simulation/odom_89
```

I need to fill the config automatically with the values for `from_domain` and `to_domain`
I tried to use `yaml.dump()` and create a dictionary with the corresponding structure. However, it failed because I cannot use the same key, `simulation/odometry`, twice.